# getElementsByTagName not finding proper nodes

Tags: java, dom, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to get a node called "value" from this XML document and read the text content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.gmail.pavilion99</groupId>
    <artifactId>ValdeonScrim</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.16-20140802.182613-1</version>
    <versioning>
        <snapshot>
            <timestamp>20140802.183132</timestamp>
            <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
        </snapshot>
        <lastUpdated>20140802183148</lastUpdated>
        <snapshotVersions>
            <snapshotVersion>
                <extension>pom</extension>
                <value>0.8.16-20140802.183132-2</value>
                <updated>20140802183132</updated>
            </snapshotVersion>
            <snapshotVersion>
                <extension>jar</extension>
                <value>0.8.16-20140802.183132-2</value>
                <updated>20140802183132</updated>
            </snapshotVersion>
        </snapshotVersions>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

With this java code:

```
Document doc = builder.parse(new URL("http://localhost:8081/artifactory/list/plugins-snapshot-local/com/gmail/pavilion99/ValdeonScrim/maven-metadata.xml").openStream());
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("latest");

Document doc2 = builder.parse(new URL("http://localhost:8081/artifactory/list/plugins-snapshot-local/com/gmail/pavilion99/ValdeonScrim/"+nodes.item(0).getTextContent()+"/maven-metadata.xml").openStream());
NodeList nodes2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("value");
for(int i = 0; i < nodes2.getLength(); i++){
    getServer().getLogger().info(nodes2.item(i).getNodeName());
}           
String downloadPath = nodes.item(0).getTextContent();
downloadPath += "/ValdeonScrim-";           
downloadPath += nodes2.item(0).getTextContent();
```

But I get a `NullPointerException` error on that last line, meaning it hasn't found any nodes.  I've been tearing my hair out for hours trying XPath and other ways of trying this and I can't figure out why it's not finding the `value` element in metadata/versioning/snapshotVersions/snapshotVersion/value.

Thanks!

Comment: Some questions, are you sure the retrieved URL for doc2 returns the expected data? What is the value of nodes2.getLength()? Do you see messages logged with the node names?

Comment: I can confirm that it does return the correct document; I had it print that to the console.  Let me check nodes2.getLength().

Edit: value of nodes2.getLength() is 0.

Comment: Strange, by parsing the XML from a string and process doc2 I get 2 'value' nodes, so that part seems OK. I suggest to validate that doc2 represents the xml after creation. Like checking that  doc2.getDocumentElement(); is the 'metadata' element.